# Using interop.MSProject.dll without Office installed or creating Project Add-in in Visual Studio

Tags: ms-office, office-interop, project-server

I need to work on Project Server using Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.dll from Visual Studio.
Using gacutil.exe I have registered Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.dll and at folder "C:\Windows\assembly" there is entry for MSProject.dll whose processor architecture is MSIL. 
I have created Console Application and when I try to create Application instance it gives error:
 Class not registered-HRESULT: 0x80040154 exception. As shown in image.
[image]Target platform for this project is x86(32-bit). What could be the reason for the error?
Is it because office is not installed on local machine? Is there any alternative to using PIA without installing Office? 
I have tried creating Project Add-in from Visual Studio, it  works successfully, but it requires Project Professional to be open, which I want to avoid. Is it possible to avoid opening of Project Professional application in this case?

Comment: `new MSProject.Application` does open Project Professional. So no, you won't launch this code without Office/MSProject installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the Application (i.e. MS Project) installed on the PC. Interop files sre used for marshalling property or method calls from a managed code to the host application.